# C - I'm getting two diferents pointers from the same variable

Tags: c, pointers

**Context**

I was studing about pointer in C, for that I was testing some pointer's algorithm and in one of this tries I make a little change that is bugging until now.

**This is the code:**

```
char *s = "ABCDEF";
char **y = &s;

printf("%p\n", s);
printf("%p\n", &s);

printf("%p\n", y);
printf("%p\n", &s[0]);
```

The problem is that for some reason when I ask for C to print the pointer of S (without the ampersand), I receive one pointer, but when I put the ampersand I receive another pointer differently.  I think that this didn't happen because the ampersand will give me the address of S.

So to check if isn't a bug, I make a pointer with the address of S, and I received the same that the "&s" as expected, but when I use the "&s[0]" I received the value of the single "s".

So, why is C giving me two results if in both cases I'm just asking for the first character of the string?

**The values that I received**

```
0x400634
ox7ffd95c33090
ox7ffd95c33090
0x400634
```

I know that probably I'm forgetting some piece of logic, but I've struggled with this, so if someone can help me, I'll appreciate it.

Comment: `&` is "address of" here. Every variable has a value, and generally that value and the address of that variable are not going to be the same.

Comment: `s` is a pointer (a separate variable of its own...) that contains the address of the `"ABCDEF"` string literal (which is *another* variable....)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The variable `s` stores the address of the string literal `"ABDCDEF"`; the variable `y` stores the address of the variable `s`.

```
    char **        char *        char
    +---+          +---+         +---+
 y: |   | ----> s: |   | ------> |'A'|
    +---+          +---+         +---+
                                 |'B'|
                                 +---+
                                 |'C'|
                                 +---+
                                 |'D'|
                                 +---+
                                 |'E'|
                                 +---+
                                 |'F'|
                                 +---+
                                 | 0 |
                                 +---+
```

Answer (score 4):

With

```
char *s = "ABCDEF";
char **y = &s;
```

you basically have this:

```
+---+     +---+     +----------+
| y | --> | s | --> | "ABCDEF" |
+---+     +---+     +----------+
```

That is, `y` points to `s`, and `s` points to (the first character of) the string `"ABCDEF"`.

Printing `y` will print where it is pointing, which is the location of the variable `s`.

Answer (score 2):

s[0] is equivalent to *(s + 0), means that the first block of that memory is dereferenced so if you write &s[0] this is equivalent to &(*(s + 0)) -> (s+0)
That is an actual pointer to the array's first element and the double-pointer can refer to a pointer, pointers themselves have addresses because they are similar to variables that store a memory address.

Answer (score 1):

```
char *s = "ABCDEF";
char **y = &s;

printf("%p\n", s);      /* address of the 'A' in the string literal "ABCDED" */
printf("%p\n", &s);     /* address of the local variable s */

printf("%p\n", y);      /* contents of y, which is the address of the local variable s */
printf("%p\n", &s[0]);  /* address of the 'A' in the string literal */
```

Maybe it helps to think of `s[0]` as `*s`, in which case you can rewrite `&s[0]` as `&*s` and see that the `&` and the `*` operators "cancel" (in a very non-technical sense) each other.

Answer (score 0):

> the pointer **of** S (without the ampersand)

This is already confusing. `char *s` declares `s` **as** a pointer.

> but when I put the ampersand I receive **another** pointer

That other pointer can be called *pointer of* (or to) `s`. A pointer to a pointer (to char).

> address of S

"pointer of" and "address of" must mean the same. Nobody says "pointer of s" in that context above.